# Instant of interface and class

Tags: java

In my code I have seen difference between instant of interface and instant of class that implement it , why ??
I have method that return array of objects of class and implements an interface which declare this method , when create instant  of class and invoke this method the returned value is different if it was invoked by interface instant although it should do the same job , the returned value is different , why??

```
public interface A{
    public B[] m();
}

public class B implements A {

    public B[] m() {
        B b[]=new B[10];

        for(int i=0; i>10; i++)
            b[i]=new B();

        return b;
    }
}
```

In this part when I try to create two instant one for class and another for interface then invoke the method for each one like :

```
B obj1=new B();
A obj2=new B();

System.out.println(obj1.m().equals(obj2.m)); 
System.out.println( obj1.m()[0].equals(obj2.m()[0]) );
........
```

This returned false.

Maybe it is clear `obj1` is not `obj2`, but why is the returned value different and how can I get same returned value if possible?

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of your code have nothing to do with the compile time type of `obj1` (`B`) vs. `obj2` (`A`).

The reasons your comparisons return `false` :

1. Comparing the arrays would always return false for two distinct arrays, since arrays don't override `Object`'s `equals` method.
2. Comparing the first element of the two arrays also returns false, since your `B` class doesn't override the `equals` method, so `obj1.m()[0].equals(obj2.m()[0])` is false since `obj1.m()[0] != obj2.m()[0]`. It can only return true if your `B` class would have an implementation of `public boolean equals (Object other)` that may return true.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing objects, that will never be same, unless you override the equals method.
You should compare the contents.
There is no difference between declaring objects, in your case

Case1:    B obj1=new B();

Case2:    A onj2=new B();

In case1 you are directly assigning to Object B so you are eligible to call method specific to B along with implemented methods from A.

In Case2 you are only eligible to call the methods implemented from Interface A

It is called polymorphism.

Correcting your code will give the right answer, as answered by Eran

Comment: Thanks for your responses

Comment: Thanks for your responses ,
so you means obj1.m() vs obj1.m() and obj1.m()[0] vs obj2m()[0]  are equals in general and when there is equal method implementation should return true not false !

Comment: Your class B should have equals method to compare objects, when you say obj1.m().equals(obj2.m) there should be some way to compare object returned by m() (B). Other wise it will return just reference that cannot be same for 2 objects.

Comment: For  obj1.m()[0] vs obj2m()[0] you need equals method to be implemented